# sku code as description in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

In the Google Analytics ecommerce tracing script you must provide for every item and SKU code. I have this code for every product I'm selling and up until now I have always provided it in the `_addItem` method.

But when reviewing that data in the ecommerce module of Google Analytics, I have no real, no readable data about my SKU sales. I know what product has been sold, due to the product name I provide. But when clicking through to the SKU-level, I know nothing more, since all I can see there are SKU codes.

Is it possible and wise to replace the SKU code with the following template?

```
"product-name colour-name size-name"
```

This way, it should still be a unique field, but more readable afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just pass the `name` into the `addItem` method:-

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
```

How you can customise/extend this will largely depend upon the ecommerce platform you are using and what attributes you can pass in via `addItem`.

Comment: do you mean for me to add a new argument in the addItem method, named ´name´, or are you referring to the existing ´product name´ argument?

Comment: I'm referring to what should be the existing providing your custom ecommerce tracking or ecommerce platform catered for this item correctly. Using the above should yield products by name in Google Analytics' Ecommerce section.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I see now - you wish to show more than just the SKU in the SKU report. Providing the tracking is installed correctly, surely you can just add multiple dimensions in GA to display the product name with the SKU's. Would this not suffice?

Comment: my products are clothes, no colour or size specified. So the product name argument has for example 'pants'.
The SKU-code fields contains the sku-value from my database, a code that indicates a product on colour- and size-level. Right now it contains just a code, like '123456789'.
When I look at this in Google Analytics, I get a list of all product names, which is fine, but when I open the SKU-codes view, I get a list of codes, which says nothing in particular.

I want to know if I can replace this code with words (and spaces), for example 'pants blue medium'. And if it is recommended to do so.